# Binding across tab items with button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf with multiple tabs. The application is a step by step learning tool for students. I want the tabs to be locked initially. When the user has entered the correct data in a tab, the next is enabled after pressing the proceed button.

I tried binding the 'isEnabled' property of tabitem and setting it true when the button is pressed in the View model. It doesn't work.

Here's some snippets of my code:
XAML:

```html
<TabItem Header="Step 1"><my:Step1 Loaded="Step1_Loaded" /></TabItem>
 <TabItem Header="Step 2"><my:Step2 Loaded="Step2_Loaded" /></TabItem>
 <TabItem IsEnabled="{Binding step3Enabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Step 3"><my:Step3 Loaded="Step3_Loaded" /></TabItem>
```

Code-behind for the button:

```css
private void proceed2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = DataContext as ViewModel.ValuesCheck;
            if (vm != null)
               vm.Step2check();
           
        }
```

View Model:

```css
class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool _step3enabled = false;
        public bool step3Enabled
        {
            get { return _step3enabled; }
            set { _step3enabled = value; OnPropertyChanged("step3Enabled"); }
        }
        public void Step2check()
        {
             this.step3Enabled = true;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        { 
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have binding errors? It's unclear if you actually create an instance of `ViewModel` and set it as `DataContext` somewhere. Talking about design: consider to use MVVM, each tab is a separate ViewModel, you may create some progress control to show total number of questions and current one and simply use `ContentControl` to display current question.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you need some navigation control that presents its content based on some condition. I can suggest you to use a listbox control and manage its ListBoxItems content visibility or something like this.

1. Xaml:

   ```
   <Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
       <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentControlContent}"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
       <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Border Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding Path = TabIsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"
                       BorderBrush="Tomato" BorderThickness="1" IsEnabled="{Binding Path = TabIsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                   <Button Width="100" Height="30" IsEnabled="{Binding Path = TabIsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                           IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{Binding Path = Content, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Button>
               </Border>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
   <Grid Grid.Row="1">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentControlContent.Content}"></ContentControl>
       <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Check" Command="{Binding CheckCommand}"></Button>
   </Grid>
   ```
2. ViewModel

   ```
       private TabAndControlModel _selectedTabControlModel;
   private ICommand _checkCommand;
   private TabAndControlModel _currentControlContent;
   public ObservableCollection<TabAndControlModel> Controls { get; set; }

   public TabAndControlModel CurrentControlContent
   {
       get { return _currentControlContent; }
       set
       {
           _currentControlContent = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   public ICommand CheckCommand
   {
       get { return _checkCommand ?? (_checkCommand = new RelayCommand(Check)); }
   }

   private void Check()
   {
       var index = Controls.IndexOf(CurrentControlContent);
       var nextIndex = index + 1;
       if(nextIndex >= Controls.Count) return;
       CurrentControlContent = Controls[nextIndex];
       CurrentControlContent.TabIsEnabled = true;

   }
   ```
3. Model

   ```
       private bool _tabIsEnabled;
   private string _content;

   public bool TabIsEnabled
   {
       get { return _tabIsEnabled; }
       set
       {
           _tabIsEnabled = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }

   public string Content
   {
       get { return _content; }
       set
       {
           _content = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
   }
   ```
4. View on running:
   [image]
5. And you have to template and style all that stuff...

Regards